# What is the purpose of JavaScript's call and apply methods?

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of call and apply methods in the language?

It seems to be an example of anti-pattern which breaks OOP principles. Or it just presents multi-paradigm approach?

This example made me to ask this question.

In one place of application (a part of library) there is such a code

```
socket.emit = function() {
    if (!socket.banned) {
      emit.apply(socket, arguments)
    }
 }
```

In another part of application (self written) there is such piece of code

```
socket.emit = function(arguments){
    data = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    emit.apply(socket, data);
}
```

In the first place the object should not work if it is banned. But the second part knows nothing about library logic and works independently.

How this situations may be resolved? We use libraries to ease the most difficult parts.

Comment: The purpose is to invoke a function with a specific calling context, the `this`, and any number of `arguments`. Other than that, it's not really clear what you need to know. If this is a question about programming principles, maybe this is better suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In your second case, why did you choose the name `arguments` for your formal parameter? Doing so shadows the `arguments` object, since the identifier `arguments` now refers to the first argument of the function, instead of the default object called `arguments` that has access to all arguments passed into the function. Do you expect `emit` to be called with an array-like object as its first parameter? If you did `emit = function(firstArg){ ...` and `slice.call(firstArg);` the functionality would be much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Function.prototype.call` exists for *one* purpose only, and this is to allow the function to be called with a specific value of `this`, i.e. the one that's passed as the first parameter.

`Function.prototype.apply` is the same, but with the added advantage that the array passed as the second parameter is split out into *multiple parameters* when the function is invoked.  This is useful when you want to call a function that takes a variable sized list of arguments but you have those arguments ready in an array instead of as individual values.

Take, for example, `Math.max`.   If I have a set of unknown size and I wish to find the largest there are two approaches:

1. successively compare each element against the current maximum until you find the largest
2. pass all of them directly to `Math.max`.

I can't call `Math.max(a, b, c, etc)` because I don't know how many variables there are.   Instead I can call `Math.max.apply(null, myArray)` and that gets expanded to `Math.max(myArray[0], myArray[1], etc)`.

NB1: in ES6 `.apply` isn't strictly required any more because you can use `.call` with the `...` spread operator, e.g. `Math.max.call(null, ...myArray)`.

NB2: this has *nothing* to do with breaking OOP principles.